# System.PlatformNotSupportedException after Cumulative patch

Tags: cumulative-update

I just installed a Hotfix (Cumulative patch) on my windows 2003 server, running SP2007 sp2 as I was having trouble with Delay Activity and now get the following error in Visual Studio when entering debug mode with workflow. Any ideas how to cure this ?

**Installed :**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553022

wsskb2553022fullfilex86glb

WSS3.0

12.0000.6565.5001

31416952

8/30/2011 6:11:52 PM

**Error in vs debug mode:**

Error 1 Exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' was thrown.

Comment: did you try running the configuration wizard after applying the patch? Please also accept answers for your questions so that you get good responses in the future.

Comment: Visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm your project is not pointing to .NET 4.0.  It may have changed due to an update.

Comment: I ran configuration wizard, project uses .net3.5, re-installed VS2010, re-installed .net 3.5.

But no luck, cannot remove patch either in add/remove programs. looks like a re-install of wss3sp2 :(

Answer (score 1):

CHeck the Platform under your project's Build Tab, it should be set to AnyCPU, not x64 or or x86